# Problema al unir llaves foráneas a tablas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-management

Estoy tratando de unir 2 tablas por una llave

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de unir, me sale esta opcion, pero yo sólo quiero 2 llaves

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me manda este error, se refiere a que debo crear una clave primario para la tabla reserva producto, pero en otras tablas no la cree y me funciono normal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a qué te refieres con "yo solo quiero 2 llaves"?, y cuál es el error que recibes?

Comment: Olvidé subirlo, ya está

Comment: cuando relacionas tablas, la tabla que quieres relacionar debe hacer referencia a la llave completa de la otra tabla. No puedes hacer relación a una parte de la llave

Comment: La tabla no tiene 2 llaves, tiene una sola llave compuesta.